# I am making a C program that only takes input between 1 & 8 in C . What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c, limit, do-while, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
     n = get_int("Enter a number between 1 and 8(including 8):  ");
    }
    while ((n<1) && (n>8));
    printf("%d\n",n);

}
```

Comment: `n < 1` is true (and produces value 1) if `n` is less than 1. `n > 8` is true if `n` is greater than `8`. `(n < 1) && (n > 8)` is true if and only if both of these things are true. They are never both true, since `n` is never both less than 1 and greater than 8.

Comment: Hint: google "de Morgan theorem"

Comment: A number can never be less than 1 AND greater than 8 at the same time, therefore the condition of the do-while loop is never true. The condition should be to continue repeating the loop while n is less than 1 OR greater than 8.

Answer (score 4):

The condition `(n<1) && (n>8)` will never be true because no numbers are less than 1 while they are greater than 8.

You should use `(n<1) || (n>8)` instead.

Comment: While your statement is right, the OP also want it between `8` and `1`, or maybe I getting it wrong?

Comment: @ROOT Sorry, I don't understand you well. Do you think this won't be "between `8` and `1`"?

Comment: @MikeCAT, yes thats what I mean.

Comment: @ROOT Why do you think so?

Comment: @MikeCAT, sorry my friend, never mind it, I didn't see it, my bad.

Comment: @singhsokhal Don´t forget to accept this answer, if it solved your problem.